# how to pass query string object in http.request in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I already have a request object. Now all i have to do is change the host and make http request again.
//URL type : www.something.com/a/b?w=2&e=2

```
fun(req,res){

 options = {
   host : <newhost>
   method : req.method
   path : req.path
   headers : req.headers
  }
  http.request(options,...)
}
```

Now how do i send query string(w=2&e=2) in this option.
I can do it using request module(in nodejs) but that follows redirect(HTTP 302) as well.

Thanks,
Shantanu

Comment: You can tell request to not follow redirects.  `followRedirect: false`

Comment: that worked..thanks a lot..can u post this as answer.

Answer (score 2):

`http` can do this as well

```
var queryString = 'w=2&e=2';
options = {
   host : <newhost>
   method : req.method
   path : req.path + '?' + queryString // say, var queryString = 'w=2&e=2'  
   headers : req.headers
  }
  http.request(options,...)
```

Comment: This seems to not work, I have request that send query string with github token and if I use browser I got the response but in node I get rate limit error.

Answer (score 2):

A better way is to stringify an object with nodes querystring module. This way you can pass an options object to a custom queryBuilder function and reuse it for multiple requests of varying values. Here is a basic example.

```
    var querystring = require('querystring');
    var http = require('http');

    var options = {
        host : 'www.host.com',
        path : ''
    }

    var queryBuilder = function (object, callback) {
        callback(querystring.stringify(object));
    };

    queryBuilder({ w: '2', e: '2' }, callback(data){
        options.path = data;
        http.request(options, function (req, res) {
            //do something with the response
        }).end();
    });
```

this will set the path equal to `w=2&e=2`

Comment: Thanks, a little typo: `querysring` should be `querystring`